# Como imprimir cabecalho com valores dinamico em mpdf?

Tags: php, mpdf

Pessoal tenho uma função que retorna um $html contendo uma lista de usuários,ate aqui esta funcionando. o meu problema e quando tentar gerar pdf imprimi cabeçalho com ultimo usuário da lista, não esta fazendo reset do cabeçalho ou algo semelhante.

Estou passando a variável $html dentro do método para gerar cabeçalho

mpdf->SetHeader($html);

Comment: printa o html se ele tiver saindo o ultimo usuario o problema não é o setHeader e sim o seu html

Comment: não e esse o problema porque a função esta retornado uma lista de usuário, problema esta na hora de gerar pdf, o API não esta fazendo um loop para cada dado do usuário colocando um header.

Comment: Não seria melhor utilizar o [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/), pelo menos tem um [manual](http://www.fpdf.org/) para isso.

Answer (score 2):

Cara, quando surgir uma duvida dessas vá direto na [documentação](https://mpdf.github.io/).
O setHeader do mpdf não faz o que você quer (iterar sobre uma lista de usuarios e imprimir um cabeçalho personalizado para cada um). O que você deve fazer é setar um cabeçalho diferente para cada pagina.
Exemplo com base na versão mais recente do [mpdf](https://mpdf.github.io/headers-footers/method-2.html) (tirado de lá):

```
<?php

// First ensure that you are on an Even page

$mpdf->AddPage('','E');

// Then set the headers for the next page before you add the page

$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<div style="text-align: right; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt;">Chapter 2</div>','O');

$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt;">Chapter 2</div>','E');



$mpdf->AddPage();

$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('<div style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold; font-size: 8pt; font-style: italic;">Chapter 2</div>','O');

$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('<div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 8pt; font-style: italic;">Chapter 2</div>','E');

$mpdf->WriteHTML('Rest of the document');

$mpdf->Output();
```

Basicamente você vai percorrer seu array $html, e para cada índice (ou usuário dele) adicionar uma nova pagina com um cabeçalho customizado.